# What is the time complexity of fitting a seasonal ARIMA model?

Tags: time-series, time-complexity

Say I have a univariate seasonal time series with n*m data points. (i.e. m seasons with n points each).

What will be the time complexity of fitting this time series with an ARIMA model?